# Bypass CP login

Tags: control-panel, login

I've got a very special case in a big offline installation .
For strange technical and administrative reasons, I must have 5 different Craft instances each one in it's own server (on the local network) , but all Crafts should look and act as one.
That is: for the client there is only 1 CMS.

I need the access to be centralized through a single index.php displaying a menu with all the applications.
When the client click one app, he should be redirected to the Craft CP instance ( on its own server) where that App is located. So:
App1 links to http://192.168.1.20/app1/admin/entries/app1
App2 links to http://192.168.1.32/app2/admin/entries/app2

So the number of Crafts and servers should be invisible to client.
He only cliks an app and he go to edit that App.
He don't mind if it is on a server or on another....

One of the problems I'm facing is CP login.

The 1st time the client wants to edit App1 (located on server A) has to login (on Craft's A Control Panel ) .
But if he wants to edit App2 (located on server B) has to login (on Craft's B Control Panel ) .
But I don't want he to login twice. This should be transparent...

So I'm trying to create a login form at index for he to login once.
Then I'd like to send login creadentials via AJAX to every Craft instance to be pre-logged.
Then, if client access that server, Craft will not request to login again.

Is this possible?
How can I send user & pass credentials to Craft to be pre-logged in a hidden way ?

Another "solution" could be remove CP login.
As this case is an offline installation (with no connection outside), and there's only 1 user profile, looks to me that there's no need for login. 
How could I remove it?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

For your second "solution", try the Auto Login plugin, which lets you whitelist an IP address or username(s)
https://github.com/sjelfull/craft3-autologin